Why do we write in general certain eigenfunctions with constants when the weights depend on the hamiltonian?
As a matter of habit, I've simply written out eigenfunctions of spin systems, say, with the usual normalization constants as weights, but now I'm being asked to write them in terms of Hamiltonian parameters. Until now, I never did this for generalized parameters. Is there a reason we always put
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg(|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle+|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle\bigg)$$
without taking into account magnetic exchange coupling J, for example? This has also led me down the rabbit hole of diagonalizing the spin exchange Hamiltonian and trying to extract explicitly the triplet eigenvector as above and the singlet one. I don't see where the latter comes from outside of "write something orthogonal to the other" argument.
Specifically, I'm looking at the Hamiltonian:
$$ H = J S_{1} \cdot S_{2} - h_{z} \bigg( S_{1}^{z} + S_{2}^{z} \bigg).  $$
Why aren't the eigenvectors functions of the parameters? Then, if just looking at
$$ H = J S_{1} \cdot S_{2} $$
I get that both $m=0$ states (for the triplet and the singlet) again have constant prefactors. I am writing the Hamiltonian in the usual spin-basis
$$ |\uparrow \uparrow\rangle, |\uparrow \downarrow\rangle, |\downarrow \uparrow\rangle, |\downarrow \downarrow\rangle. $$


Please use MathJax. 2. Your question is unclear. Consider to give an example.


is that an unnormalized spin eigenstate state, or is it missing parenthesis?

"Why aren't the eigenvectors functions of the parameters?" Why do you think they aren't?

The prefactors would have parameter values in them rather than constants.

what “exchange” are you talking about?  You just happened to write the $S=1,M=0$ state of a system with two spin-1/2.  There’s no exchange of anything here.   The $S=0,M=0$ state is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\vert \uparrow\downarrow \rangle - \vert\downarrow\uparrow\rangle\right)$.

@ZeroTheHero J is the exchange coupling strength. I don't know what your question is. Again, as plainly as I know how to say, "why are the basis weights for this state (for example) constant; why not functions of the Hamiltonian parameters?"

Your use of “exchange “ is confusing and I don’t think it’s standard use either (I’m not 100% sure what is the exchange coupling in this context).  The term $S_1\cdot S_2$ is rather general - it can appear in multiple contexts- and the eigenstates are the spin triplet and spin singlet states.  “exchange” usually occurs in the context of permutation symmetry and an “exchange integral” is an overlap of spatial wave functions (which will depend on the permutation symmetry).  You should probably try to clarify this (if I understand correctly) in the OP.

I've added some qualifiers for "exchange."

It’s not clear what you mean here.
The eigenstates are indeed as you describe, but since $\vert \uparrow\downarrow\rangle$ and $\vert \downarrow\uparrow\rangle$ have the same eigenvalue, any linear combination of them is also an eigenstate.  Thus, the statement that both the singlet triple states are symmetric is non-sense: the singlet is still antisymmetric and still an eigenstate, and the most general eigenstate with $m=0$ is
$$
\cos\theta\, \vert \uparrow\downarrow\rangle + e^{i\varphi}\sin\theta\,\vert \downarrow\uparrow\rangle \tag{1}
$$
which does not have any particular (permutation) symmetry.  In fact, two eigenstates of the form (1) need not be orthogonal, although in practice we would almost always make them so.
Of course in general the eigenstates will depend on the parameters of the Hamiltonian.  Take as an example
$$
H=JS^z_1\cdot S^z_2-h_x (S_1^x+S_2^2)\, . \tag{2}
$$
The difference between Eq.(2) and your case is that the second term in $H$ does not commute with the first, so the eigenstates of (2) are no longer simply spin-up/spin-down products.  The eigenstates of (2) do depend in $J$ and $h_x$.

Yes, of course the singlet is antisymmetric. I will work out the eigenstates of (2) to see what you mean. Thanks.

If you can edit your question and clarify your “I get that both $m=0$ states (for the triplet and the singlet) are symmetric” that would also be useful.

Why are you explicit with "permutation" symmetry? Is there some underlying law/rule that says permutation symmetry yields unity factors in the un-normalized eigenvectors? I see that when Sz(total) is conserved, that is the case. Is there a more general statement about it?

There is no such law.  It just happens to hold true for two spin-1/2.  In general the states with definite permutation symmetry will have complicated factors, not necessarily equal.

Why is that you can say automatically that because the first two terms don't commute, the eigenstates will depend on the parameters? Is this a rule? I know that good quantum numbers are defined as operators commuting with H and that those are good labels for states.

it is in general true that eigenstates of $H$ depend on the parameters.  You just happen to propose case where $S_1\cdot S_2$ commutes with $S_1^z+S_2^z$ so they have common eigenvectors, which are eigenstates of $S_1^z+S_2^z$ and these do not depend on the parameters in $H$ since $k(S_1^z+S_2^z)$ have the same eigenstates for all $k$.

This seems to be the answer I'm looking for. I need to think about this a bit. Thank you.

A spin state by itself is not an eigenfunction for a hamiltonian, they are eigenfunctions of the spin operators. That is, in the $S_z$ basis, the associated spin states in the $X$ direction are
$$|S_x,\pm\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|S_z,+\rangle \pm|S_z,-\rangle \right) .$$
The full quantum state, considering spin and the hamiltonian, would be something like $|\Psi\rangle=|S_\Psi\rangle\otimes |\psi\rangle(r,\theta,\phi)$, the tensor product of a spin eigenfunction and a spatial wavefunction. I assume that you are given some hamiltonian $H$ that has its own eigenfunction, is that correct? Then you have to normalize the full quantum state, which may contain another normalization for the spin state.
